# How to add a UIBarButton programmatically AT a particular INDEX

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibarbuttonitem

Currently i have a UIToolbar with 3 UIBarbuttons with indexes:
Share: 0
Flexible space: 1
Play: 2
Flexible space: 3
Trash : 4

I want to be able to replace UIBarbutton at index 2 with another UIBarButtonItem programmatically. I know one way is to create an array and create all the bar buttons programmatically and manage the array accordingly. But here I have created everything in IB and want to change only 1 button on click (because you simply cannot change play to pause action in UIBarButtonItem).

EDIT: Particularly looking to REPLACE because editing Identifier in existing UIBarButtonItem programmatically is not possible.

Comment: You can change the 2nd button details instead of removing and adding new button.

Comment: I tried to change the identifier but it wouldnt let me... not sure if im going wrong with the syntax anywhere, resources online say that changing an identifier is not possible unless you create a button programmatically with a diff identifier? let me now your thoughts or solutions

Comment: Can you show the code how you create your UIToolBar?

Comment: Creating the UIToolbar and other UIBarbuttons including the play button is done completely on the IB and not programmatically. Which is why I was wondering if theres a way to change the identifier of a barbuttonitem without actually creating it programmatically(which is what other posts talk about).